# How do I get my stopwatch to keep running over scenes and not reset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a student and I'm having trouble getting my stopwatch to keep going over scenes and keep going when I reload scenes without resetting, here's my code.

```
public class Stopwatch : MonoBehaviour
{
    float timer;
    float seconds;
    float minutes;
    float hours;

    bool start;

    [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI stopWatchText;

    private void Start()
    {
        start = false;
        timer = 0;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        StopWatchCalcul();
    }

    void StopWatchCalcul()
    {
        if (start)
        { 
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            seconds = (int)(timer % 60);
            minutes = (int)((timer / 60) % 60);
            hours = (int)(timer / 3600);

            stopWatchText.text = hours.ToString("00") + ":" + minutes.ToString("00") + ":" + seconds.ToString("00");
        }
    }
    public void startTimer()
    {
        start = true;
    }

    public void stopTimer()
    {
        start = false;
    }

    public void resetTimer()
    {
        start = false;
        timer = 0;
        stopWatchText.text = "00:00:00";
    }
}
```

I tried using PlayerPrefs but couldn't get them to work to save it my stopwatch just resets when the scene switches and when the scene reloads. I also tried creating a separate variable to store the stopwatch value but didn't where to put it.

I was expecting the time to keep going across scenes and when the scene reloads.

Comment: One easy solution is to make `timer` and `start` fields `static`. Also, check out [Time.realtimeSinceStartup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-realtimeSinceStartup.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the object your script is attached to, to not destroy on load > https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Comment: Where would I add that inside of my code. Never mind I got it, thanks.

Comment: make sure to also destroy duplicate instances though otherwise after loading the same scene 3 times you get 3 stopwatches running ;)

Comment: How would I add that?

Comment: just make sure there are not duplicate timers by either only having 1 timer in the starting scene or deleting the spare timers each time a scene starts